# Stored Procedure For Mysql Database from c# WinApp

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

this is my first post...
I'm some confused on this my issue.
In my WinApp I would like to populate a ListView from data retrivet from a Store Procedure that accept 3 parameters: 2 date (for to build the date...between construct) and a text items into DropDownList.
My "Idea" on how to implement this, is that on SelectedIndexChanged of DropDownList, run the c# code that execute the Stored Procedure, but I haven't any idea on how to make 
It's the right method?
The stored prodedure must be stored on Mysql engine or I must inject into it via c# code?
How I can execute it, with parametr, from my app?
I'm really confused...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a simple plain how to start tutorial. I would suggest use google to find some basic hello world tutorials on MySQL using C#.

For example take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CS_MYSql_Stored_Procedure.aspx). It covers stored procedures of My SQL with a simple C# app

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I'd study this articles many times but I'm a novice and some things I don't know.There is a minimal example that call a stored procedure with parameter and show me result on ListView or any sililar objects?Thanks again